# Hide fields based on selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown menu for categories where you can select a type of property like (colocation, sell, buy)
and based on that selection fields will show to add extra information's

But every selection need specific type of fields

For I'm using jQuery but I don't know how to show fields based on every selection

Html code for menu :

```
<select name="prop_category" id="prop_category_submit" class="select-submit2">
<option value="-1">Aucun</option>
<option class="level-0" value="149">Colocation</option>
<option class="level-1" value="150">colocation études</option>
<option class="level-1" value="151">Colocation pour travail</option>
<option class="level-1" value="440">Vacance</option>
<option class="level-0" value="72">Luxe</option>
<option class="level-1" value="76">Appartement</option>
</select>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery("#prop_category_submit").change(function(){
        const currentVal = jQuery("#prop_category_submit").val();
        let imputList = ["property_size","property_lot_size"];
        if (['149','150','151','440','72','76'].includes(currentVal)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < imputList.length; i++) { 
               const elmnt = imputList[i];
               jQuery("#"+elmnt).parent().css({'display':'none'});
            }
        }else{
            for (let i = 0; i < imputList.length; i++) { 
               const elmnt = imputList[i];
               jQuery("#"+elmnt).parent().css({'display':'block'});
            }
        }
    });
```

Submit form

```
<div class="profile-onprofile row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
<label for="property_size"> Superficie en m<sup>2</sup>  .</label>
    <input type="number" id="property_size" size="40" class="form-control" name="property_size" value="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <label for="property_lot_size"> Superficie du lot en m<sup>2</sup> . </label>
    <input type="number" id="property_lot_size" size="40" class="form-control" name="property_lot_size" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a clear example of what `<input>` elements would be required by which `<option>`? Ideally strip down your `<select>` to two or three `<option>` elements, and then show enough of your `<form>` that we can understand what maps to what?

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas for taking time to reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/71737434/6736501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this question by using this code

```
jQuery("#prop_category_submit").change(function(){
            const currentVal = jQuery("#prop_category_submit").val();
            let imputList = ["property_rooms","property_bedrooms","property_bathrooms", "meuble","property_size"];
            if (['65','37','66','68','70','69','67','71','27'].includes(currentVal)) {
                if(currentVal=="65"){ //Terrains
                    jQuery("#property_rooms").parent().css('display','none');
                    jQuery("#property_bedrooms").parent().css('display','block');
                    jQuery("#property_bathrooms").parent().css('display','block');
                    jQuery("#meuble").parent().css('display','block');
                    jQuery("#property_lot_size").parent().css('display','none');
                    jQuery("#property-garage").parent().css('display','block');
                    jQuery("#property_size").parent().css('display','block');
                }
 }else{
                for (let i = 0; i < imputList.length; i++) { 
                   const elmnt = imputList[i];
                   jQuery("#"+elmnt).parent().css({'display':'block'});
                }
            }
        });
```